# Anyone know how to edit the VC++ directories in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2008, gdk

Right now we are configuring a lab at the college to use the DarkGDK with Visual Studio 2008.  Here is a link for those of you who are unfamiliar: [check it out here](http://www.thegamecreators.com/?m=view_product&id=2128)

Considering how tedious the installation and setup is, I've decided to write a batch script for an unattended installation which is working fine. In order for it to be finished though, I have to somehow find a way to add some global Vc++ directories through the tools->options->projects and solutions->vc++ directories dialog box within visual studio.

This script is also going to be used by students to install dark on their own PCs so configuring one machine and re-imaging the lab is not an option.

Does anyone know where VS2008 reads and writes this data? I'm talking specifically about the include and lib directories. At this point I'm thinking that I can just append the directories to this file or write a registry key if I have to (as much as I hate to mess with the registry).

Also if anyone knows of a command to add these paths that would be much easier.

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon.  Start it, change a setting, look at the ProcMon trace to see what got updated.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's a very useful little tool which i'm sure i'll be using again in the future. helped me find the file that I need to edit.

Comment: Good.  Post what you found and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Visual Studio reads and writes the pathnames to a file called vccomponents.dat which is located in the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0 directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio reads and writes the pathnames to a file called vccomponents.dat which is located in the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0 directory